# obtener el todos de la lista select jquery

Tags: jquery, .net

He intentado utilizar el formato de bloque de código, pero sigo encontrando problemas. Si alguien tiene experiencia con la visualización efectiva de código HTML  o puede proporcionar ideas sobre lo que podría estar causando este error, agradecería enormemente su ayuda.

Gracias de antemano por su ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola, esta pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al español, que es el idioma oficial de Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor, tradúcela para que pueda ser reabierta.

Comment: listo, gracias por avisarme.

Comment: Gracias por actualizarla tan rápido. He reabierto la pregunta al no estar en inglés, deberías editarla para añadir algo más de detalle (qué error recibes, qué esperas y qué recibes) y, a ser posible, añade el código en modo texto para que sea más sencillo para otros usuarios el ayudarte. Lee sobre cómo crear un [mcve].